# Login with Facebook in JavaScript ReferenceError: FB is not defined

Tags: javascript, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

The `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)` doesn't work, not sign in in Firebase, I don't know what is, the console prints:

> Object { code: "auth/operation-not-supported-in-thi…", message: "This operation is not supported in …", stack: "" }

```js
function toggleSignIn() {
  if (!firebase.auth().currentUser) {
    console.log("!firebase.auth().currentUser yes");
    var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('user_birthday');
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
      console.log("!firebase.auth().currentUser yes");
      var token = result.credential.accessToken;
      var user = result.user;
      document.getElementById('quickstart-oauthtoken').textContent = token;
  }).catch(function(error) {
    var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      var email = error.email;
      var credential = error.credential;
      if (errorCode === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
        alert('You have already signed up with a different auth provider for that email.');
        } else {
        console.error(error);
      }
    });
  } else {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  }
  document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: I also noticed you are requesting additional scopes, Firebase 4.0.0 now returns additional IdP data related to the scope you requested. Check https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.html#.AdditionalUserInfo, you can get that data from result. additionalUserInfo object.

Answer (score 0):

First: Can you check you've enabled Facebook fully in the Firebase Console: if you follow go to https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/providers and select your app, check the Facebook section has the appropriate values configured from the Facebook console.

Second: Make sure you are running from a web server. [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart) is a great way to run locally (`firebase init`, `firebase serve`), but any web server will do. The signInWithPopup doesn't work from a file that is just opened in the browser.

Comment: the authentication is enabled, with Id App and secret id, and i have in facebook developers the URI  to Auth

Comment: Could you post the full details of the error you received (the full text in the object)

Comment: ReferenceError: provider is not defined[Saber más]  facebook-popup.html:39:9
 toggleSignIn

Comment: in this line firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) { doesn't works

Comment: Hmm, the code snippet looks OK, and its weird as I can see you define provider there. Is there any other reference that could be masking it/is this code online anywhere I could see it running?

Comment: You're missing:         var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

Comment: i do, but console puts !firebase.auth().currentUser yes  facebook-popup.html:41:9
Object { code: "auth/operation-not-supported-in-thi…", message: "This operation is not supported in …", stack: "" }

Comment: Aha, think I have it - updated answer. You need to run a local webserver to try it.

Comment: Hey Montero, signInWithPopup only works from an http/https or chrome extension environment which supports web storage. You must be running it from a different environment. The error.message field should contain the details.

Comment: Which extension of chrome you recommended